# Cypress.io setting alias to an element that appears twice adds a space to the alias value

Tags: automation, cypress

I am setting alias values and then comparing them but I'm running into an issue because the element is listed twice within the same top level class. This is causing the alias value to be "latest latest", Cypress is adding a space automatically.  I thought I would be able to just say .first() and then alias it but it still adds a space.

Here's my code:

```
      cy.get('[data-automation="data-row-value-currentVersion"]')
        .first() // using first() b/c UpdatedBy nested block repeats the current version value
        .invoke('text').then(currentVersion => {
          cy.wrap(currentVersion).as('currentVersion');
        });

      cy.get('[data-automation="active-version"]')
        .invoke('text').then(activeVersion => {
          cy.wrap(activeVersion).as('activeVersion');
        });

      cy.get('@activeVersion').then(activeVersion => {
        cy.get('@currentVersion').then(currentVersion => {
          cy.log(`-${activeVersion}-`);
          cy.log(`--${currentVersion}--`);
          expect(activeVersion).to.eq(currentVersion);
        });
      });
    });
```

The assert fails because of the space that Cypress automatically adds.The cy.logs were just for me to actually see what value was being aliased.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `cy.wrap(currentVersion.trim())`

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work.  :(

Comment: Update:  I changed it to string literal format and then used .trim() and it worked!

expect(`${activeVersion.trim()}`).to.eq(`${currentVersion.trim()}`);